# How can I monitor user activities in my app without touching the main class that extends Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-testing

Suppose an app project is already written, all you want to do is to additionally write a somehow standalone script that captures the onClick, onFocusChange or even onAppear in the app. Is that even feasible? How robust is the approach?

All answer I found was to fully add listeners (or global listeners, although less comprehensively functional) for each item or so, which is a boring work for a large project, and not always desired at the end of a production process(where I just cut in).

Another purposed approach was to locate the root of the nodes and scan from there? Correct me if that's a dead end. Other answer mentioned spying app, which is not the case, since it's the original developer who wants to track everything from inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if this solves your problem but have your extension of views. Eg: `MyTextView extends TextView` then just override the touchEventHandlers, log what you want and dispatch the event down to the listeners.

So instead of normal `TextViews`, use  `MyTextView`.